# Android Location based

Tags: android, notifications, location, alarm

If u want to fire (alarm,notification etc) on user's phone based on location found, so i want to know about which method is needs to use.
Its like location based alarm.
please show me some example, it will very helpful.

Comment: Try a tutorial or 2. When you have a specific problem explain it here. Go ahead, it could be done with a few classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;

import com.gs.mobile.Constants;
import com.gs.mobile.R;

public class MyLocation {
    private Timer timer1;
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationResult locationResult;
    private boolean gps_enabled=false;
    private boolean network_enabled=false;
    private AlertDialog.Builder dialog;

    public boolean getLocation(final Context context, LocationResult result){
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled){
            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
            /*dialog.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS );
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);
                    Util.getGPS((Activity) context,locationResult);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton(Constants.TEXT_CANCEL, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });*/
            dialog.show();

        }
         if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}//MyLocation-class
```

Calling this from an activity is as shown below

```
/* Used to Get Device GPS Location
     * <uses-permission android:name=�android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION�>
     */
    public static LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){

        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    public static void getGPS(Activity _activity){
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(_activity, locationResult);

    }//getGPS()

    public static void getGPS(Activity _activity,LocationResult locationResult){
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(_activity, locationResult);

    }//getGPS()
```

every time when the lat and lang changed Your  public void gotLocation(Location location) method will be called where you can check whether the location comes under you expected or not.

If you want, even you can make use of the URL http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=37.4188514,-122.0874526&sensor=true

where you can get the name of that lat,lang by sending to this google service.